# How would you do "who's that Pokemon?" with AI?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

How would you take an image like this [image]

and determine that as "Pikachu"? I'm basically not sure what I should search to learn how to do something like this, or if there's an API or tools of some sort that already does it. I looked at options like https://www.clarifai.com/demo, however they don't have the "models" or "trained classifiers" for something specific to my needs, so I think I'd have to build it on my own, and am not sure where to begin.

Any guidance would be appreciated. A high-level overview would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would advise using machine learning for this project. In high concepts, what you would do is feed a python program thousands of pictures of different pokemon. The program will analyze them and find patterns and store those patterns.

You can then submit other pokemon images and the python script will return the likely-hood of what the pokemon is.

The library that you use is called [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org). Google has a great guide for image recognization use with tensorflow. There they explain all the code used to recognize images and all the steps to setup tensorflow. Here is the [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex).

The good thing with tensorflow is that creating different objects for different pokemon is not hard. All you need to do is create a folder and name it then name of the pokemon. Then just drag in pictures of the pokemon from multiple different angles. You will need LOTS of pictures for this to work and hours of free time. Tensorflow does take time to learn the patterns especially since you will have A LOT of pokemon, you will need a lot of images.

If you want to speed up the process, make sure to have a fast computer!

Have fun with tensorflow! and good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an answer, but do let me know if there's a better way to do this!

https://medium.com/@dimart/pok%C3%A9mon-recognition-d3ad5cadc61e#.exd51ar8t